# Dependancy hell while reinstalling steam

Tags: steam, mesa

Steam is not working, tried reinstalling but I ended in dependancy hell. After that screen I get 32-bit libGL.so.1 file missing. Any advice here?
I have tried fixing broken packages, reinstalling nvidia driver, reinstalling mesa drivers, install libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386 library,tried to revert broken packages with aptitude to older versions-all failed. Using Lubuntu 22.04.2 Graphic card is Nvidia gtx 850m.

Tried Symantec broken packages repair, no go, no hold packages from grep, no packages from apt install --simulate ./downloaded-deb-file.deb, no strange beings in source list, sudo apt install/purge approach almost destroyed my OS as it purged hundreds of files, but lucky they have recovered.

Currently although grep doesn't show me hold packages, apt get-update get-upgrade is:
mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
When I do:
`$ sudo apt-mark unhold mesa-va-drivers mesa-va-drivers:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386`
It returns to me as the packages are already marked as not hold... they are hold and not hold in the same time?

apt policy libeg1 return:

```
    libegl1:
Installed: 1.4.0-1
Candidate: 1.4.0-1
Version table:
*** 1.4.0-1 500
    500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8t94.png)

Comment: Copy & pasting your actual messages into your question would have been helpful; I see you've provided a picture of the text messages, alas that's harder to read & I can't copy/paste from it to look up details, thus I'll move on - you can look up details yourself though as you have access to the text messages you provided a picture of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Sadly those are from Steam installer. If I try to copy that I'm closing the window in the process. Data from terminal when running steam in it doesn't bring me such details.

Comment: You appear to have ppa(s) installed on your system (oibaf) that are the root cause of the problem. After all you have done, I am not sure there is much hope, but you could copy and paste the output of `apt policy libegl1` into your question.